# Harmonic oscillator problem - Griffiths

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, textbook-erratum

I'm solving problems about harmonic oscillator from Griffiths book (2nd ed.) and I'm stuck in the problem 2.13.
When I normalize the equation 2.51 to get $A_1$ my final wave function is complex, since $A_1$ is real and in this expression is multiplied by $i$.
But if I substitute the expression 2.54 in 2.50 I get a real wave function.
Am I doing something wrong or one of these expressions in this book has a mistake?

Comment: You should copy down these equations so that people without the text at hand can help. To see if an equation in the book has a mistake, look up the errata: http://academic.reed.edu/physics/faculty/griffiths.html

Comment: @SurgicalCommander I already saw the errata but there isn't anything about this.

Comment: Well then that means it's not a known mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you normalized eq2.51 you actually found $|A_{1}|$, the modulus of $A_1$, because the phase is irrelevant to normalization. So there is no discrepancy.

In other words the value you found for $A_{1}$ which was real, served the only purpose to normalize the wave function. But had it been $iA_{1}$ it would have served the same purpose, so in this sense the phase $(-i)^n$ in eq2.54 is conventional.